# Tabulator from table with html in td

Tags: html, tabulator

I want to use Tabulator 5 for html <table> with <td>'s containing another html like: <td><div class="myCellValue">value</div></td>. The problem is that it converts the values as "&lt;div class=&quot;myCellValue&quot;&gt;value&lt;/div&gt;" but I want it to insert the original html content. Is there a way how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

One  way woud be to add the column definitions to the table options and use a formatter for the column with the `div`:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  columns: [
    {
      title: "Name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age"
    },
    {
      title: "Height"
    },
    {
      title: "Date of Birth"
    },
    {
      title: "Gender"
    },
    {
      title: "Color",
      formatter: (cell) => cell.getValue()
    },
  ]
})
```

```css
.myCellValue {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.0.7/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.0.7/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<table id="example-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200">Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Date of Birth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Billy Bob</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>male</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>red</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary May</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>female</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <div class="myCellValue">value</div>
      </td>
      <td>14/05/1982</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, tabulator will convert any html tags in cells to html entities(like `&lt;`, `&gt;`,...). as [@Timur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15048478/timur) suggested, the only way is using column's `formatter` which also work when you create table from data object.